# Regarding a Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $m(A)>1$. Show that there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $a-b\in \mathbb Z$.

Suppose this is not correct. Then for all $a,b\in A$ such that $a-b\notin \mathbb Z$. Here I got stuck. Please give me a hint.

Comment: You should have a theorem/lemma the effect of "if $A$ is measurable, then $A-A$ contains an interval". Look for that in your text/notes and see if you can take it from there.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Does that help us, here? Just because $A-A$ contains an interval doesn't mean it contains an integer . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber that alone doesn't help... my thought is that the proof can be tweaked so that if $m(A)>1$, one can show that the interval has length at least $1$. Or, perhaps the lemma says something about the size of the interval.

Comment: Once $A$ is non-empty it contains a point, call it $a$, and then $a-a=0\in\Bbb Z$. Have you got the problem right? Must $a$ and $b$ be distinct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually, the lemma specifies an interval which includes zero, so it does help

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Presumably the $a, b$ must be distinct, so the fact that $0$ is in the interval doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I wrote this assuming the problem asks for *distinct* $a, b\in A$ with $a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$. See John Dawkins' comment.

---

HINT: For a real $r$, let $[r]$ be the *fractional part of $r$*: that is, $[r]$ is the least nonnegative real $s$ such that for some integer $z$, $z+s=r$. For example, $[2.38]=0.38$, and $[\pi]=\pi-3$.

Let $B=\{[a]: a\in A\}$. Then what is the measure of $B$, assuming $A$ does not contain any elements at integer distance apart? Why is this a problem?

Comment: @Scheweber: Cardinality of $A$ and $B$ will be same. But how can it help us? I couldn't resolve yet.

Comment: @Anupam I didn't say *cardinality*, I said *measure*. Can you see what the relationship between the measures is?

Comment: @Scheweber: Measure of $B$ is definitely less than 1...I need a little more help

Comment: @Anupam Can you show that $A$ and $B$ have the same measure? (HINT: First show this in the case where $A\subseteq [n, n+1]$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Next, use the countable additivity of Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: @Scheweber:Thank you. I have got it.

Comment: This is the same but I prefer to write it as: For $n\in \mathbb Z,$ let $A_n = A \cap [n,n+1) - n.$ Then each $A_n$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1),$ and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} m(A_n) = m(A) > 1.$ Thus the $A_n$ cannot be pairwise disjoint. Hence for some $m\ne n$ there are $x,y \in A$ such that $x-m =y-n,$ hence $y-x = n-m.$